# Can we compare value in Multi Dimensional Json encoded values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am using WordPress platform, and using ***WP_Query*** to call my data although can use custom ***MYSQL script*** if if can work.

I just want to add a where condition which can filter JSON value as below explained:

so in **postmeta table** i have a following columns

```
meta_key: _stock_reserve_outlet_extended
meta_value: a:2:{s:8:"outlet_2";a:2:{s:5:"stock";s:2:"20";s:5:"rider";s:2:"-1";}s:8:"outlet_1";a:2:{s:5:"stock";i:-4;s:5:"rider";i:0;}}
```

which is actually an array extracted as below by **get_post_meta() function**:

```
 Array ( 
      [outlet_2] => Array ( 
                            [stock] => 45 
                            [rider] => 0 
                          ) 
      [outlet_1] => Array ( 
                            [stock] => -4 
                            [rider] => 0) 
                          ) 
      )
```

i want to filter rows during calling rows from script by comparing following:
***stock > 0 in outlet_2***

I tried to search filter json values filtration by **json_search** but that does not compare by key.

To give ***WP_Query*** a try, i use following but nothing effect shows

```
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'key'     => '_stock_outlet_extended',
                    'value'   => array(
                                    'key' => 'stock',
                                    'value' => '18'
                                ),
                    'compare' => '>',
                );
```

*Then i tried following script but that not work aswell:*

```
SELECT meta_value
FROM `frbl1ozme_postmeta`
WHERE `post_id` = 3699 AND `meta_key` = '_stock_outlet_extended' AND meta_value ->'$.stock' > 1;
```

Do anyone know how to tackle this sort of criteria?

Comment: Why is there PHP serialized data involved here? IF it's actually stored like that, it's not JSON.

Comment: Please don't say "won't work", that doesn't help us understand your problem on a technical level. instead say what happened, what errors you got if any, and what output you observed.

Comment: You have to read that data from the database and then use `unserialize()` on it to make it back into a PHP data type then you  can process the resultset and keep what you want and loose what you dont. You cannot query it on the database like you could if it was JSON, assuming you had a recent enough version of MySQL to allow that

Comment: @RiggsFolly It means if i want to filter rows i have to change whole logic to insert otherwise i cant able to filter rows via queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i observer is if you are saving any array by using ***update_post_meta()*** function of wordpress then it will serialize it and you are unable to filter rows by script then.

So after understood this fact i made the changes in structure and along with the stock i am saving ***status*** according to the value condition of stock, so i can filter rows easily by MYSQL.

So in one line answer, one can not achieve filter serialize rows via mysql queries till date.

Thank you all for the Help, specially @RiggsFolly